# How can I use Gnus to access Gmail IMAP through http(s) firefwall?

Tags: gnus, email, imap, proxy

My company's firewall only allow http and https connections.

To access internet, I have to specify the proxy before connecting the internet:

```
export http_proxy=http://my-company.com
export https_proxy=http://my-company.com
```

That's the current situation.

My question is how can I use Gnus to access Gmail's IMAP server through? What's the setup? Has anyone actually done this?

I've no problem to connect Gmail's IMAP server without proxy.

I did some investigation,
looks Gnus is using openssl to connect to the Gnus.

so the first step is [ask openssl to use proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220419/openssl-s-client-using-a-proxy) (because Gnus is using openssl)
but I've not succeeded yet.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the question is, but if you're running into issues with Gnus and Gmail you might want to experiment with using something like http://isync.sourceforge.net/mbsync.html to synchronize your mail to a local Maildir and then using Gnus with the Maildir.

Comment: Do you mean you can only access gmail via HTTP(S) and not IMAP because of the firewall you're behind?  In that case, you can't.  Although you could setup another IMAP / proxy somewhere else which is accessible from your location.

Comment: my company has a firewall which allow only http and https traffic, but I want to use Gnus to access IMAP.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://zderadicka.eu/accessing-imapsmtp-via-https-proxy/

Comment: @chenbin you should edit your question to reflect what the problem really is -- that you are trying to get through a firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's specifically Emacs-related. Your problem seems to be that you only have access to ports 80/443, and Gmail doesn't provide IMAP access over those: they only have 993 open for IMAP/SSL

See https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960 for reference

So unless you can bypass your proxy (by means of an external gateway for example), you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your mail provider provides IMAP/SMTP access on ports 80/443, you are out of luck.  No email client can be tuned to give access to a port that is being blocked by a firewall.

When I am in these circumstances, I use a VPN such as OpenVPN (e.g. with a third party service provider) that CAN be accessed over these ports.

Then, you can tunnel all of your traffic (including e.g. ports 993/465) through port 443 and get the access that you desire.